# Which time series database supports these specific requirements?

Tags: elasticsearch, time-series, influxdb

We have a database with more than a **billion** **daily** statistical records. Each record has multiple metrics (m1 through m10), and several immutable tags.

Record can also be associated with zero or more groups. The idea was to use multiple tags (e.g. `g1, g2`) to indicate the belonging of specific record to specific group.

Our data is stored on daily level, and most time-series databases are really optimized for more granular data. This represents a problem when we want to produce monthly, or quarterly graphs (e.g. InfluxDB have maximum aggregation period of 7d). We need a database that is really optimized for day-level data points and can produce quick aggregations on month/quarter/year level.

Furthermore, the relationship between records and groups is mutable. We need the database to support the batch update of records (pseudo: `ADD TAG group1 TO records WHERE record_id: 101`), or at least fast deletion/reinserting of updated data. This operation should be relatively fast.

We need something that can produce near-real-time results when aggregating data across tens of millions (filtered) records.

Our original solution is based on elasticsearch and it works quite well, but wanted to explore alternatives in time-series databases niche. Can anyone recommend a time-series database that supports these features?

Comment: What do you mean by `maximum aggregation period of 7d` ? I'm able to group by as many days as I like ?  Regarding the mutable group membership, tags are not a good fit. Perhaps you could use fields instead and Flux for querying. Regarding performance, if you need monthly, and yearly reports then pre-aggregate your data to hour or day resolution at least for older data. You save space and time. I don't suppose groups change for old data ? I'd be interested in the usecase :)

Comment: That "update" is not very usual feature for TSDB. IMHO this looks like a good task for classic SQL "relational" DB e.g. PostgreSQL or "improved" versions -  TimescaleDB or Redshift.

Comment: @NikolayManolov thanks for the comment! I have only tried out influxdb a bit, and when grouping by time intervals i found this: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/spec/#durations. There is also long thread on github on whether they will support calendar (month/quarter/year) periods, but it seems not to be still available. Pre-aggregating data manually is a valid option, but i was wondering if there is perhaps a database that does that automatically. And, yes, groups change for old data as well which makes this really challenging.

Comment: @JanGaraj thanks for the comment! We did try with aurora and redshift, but response times are not very promising (even on denormalized data). We need this to be able to produce results very fast (under a second preferably) so that it can power live dashboards.

Comment: well, if you need that, I'd suggest that you do the aggregation in advance and save the results in a different database and then just query/display them from there. I don't know what your specific use case is so this is as much as I can say.

Comment: I somewhat repeated myself above. I don't know what I was responding to ...
In any case, you are able to group by `30d` - 30 days or `4w` - 4 weeks for example, so you can group by more than 7 days but you are right that you can't do it by calendar month/quarter/year. You could do day aggregation and do additional aggregation "outside" and push the results back. Or something of that sort.

Comment: Thanks @NikolayManolov for your comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [ClickHouse](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickHouse). It is optimized for real-time processing and querying big amounts of data. We successfully used it to store hundreds of billions of records per day on a 15-node cluster. ClickHouse is able to scan billions of records per second per CPU core and its query performance scales linearly with the number of available CPU cores.

ClickHouse also supports infrequent data updates, so you can update groups for particular rows.

If you want more tradituonal TSDB, then take a look at [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics). It is built on architecture ideas from ClickHouse, so it is fast and provides good on-disk data compression.

Comment: Thanks @valyala! ClickHouse does seem very interesting. Could you recommend some good managed service for it?

Comment: There is [managed service from Yandex](https://cloud.yandex.com/services/managed-clickhouse), but I have no experience with it.

Answer (score 0):

With the disclaimer that I work for the company that develops this system, I want to say that you may want to take a look at CrateDB as I think it is a good fit for the requirements you mention, it is optimized for fast aggregations on large amounts of data, it supports updates, and you can query the data with the full flexibility of the standard SQL language, including joins, CTEs, window functions, and subqueries. It also has many other features that you may find useful like support for flexible schemas, full text search, etc.
CrateDB is open source and you can run it on-premises, but I notice you were looking for a fully managed service and we also offer that, CrateDB Cloud, which has a free tier in case you want to give it a try.